# Content offset for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener, contentoffset

I want to calculate vertical or horizontal offset at runtime. The height of each row is not equal for my case.

To do this task, I tried some methods. But the result was not expected.

**computeHorizontalScrollOffset**: the length of the thumb within the scrollbar's track.

**setOnScrollChangeListener**: onScrollChange returns zero for scrollX and scrollY everytime

**setOnScrollListener**: Calculate over all value

```
recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                overallScrollY += dy; 
            }
        });
```

Latest solution works. But it doesn't calculate vertical offset properly. Calculated value and expected value is different.

Comment: If I understand your question, you want to know how many pixels you have scrolled down into a `RecyclerVIew` and that amount is measured from the top of the first item in the `RecyclerView` which may not be displayed to the top of the first displayed item on the screen. Is that correct? Since your items vary in height, does it need to be accurate to the nearest pixel?

Comment: @Cheticamp yes, you are right

Comment: What are you expecting and what are you seeing? Are you starting at the top of the `RecyclerView`?